# urlopen fails with getaddrinfo error

Tags: python, csv, urllib, urlretrieve

I deleted my python 2.7 and installed the new 3.X version(conda). Then the  `urlopen` just did not work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
```

returns URLError: **urlopen error [Errno 10093] getaddrinfo failed.** What I am trying to do is `urlretrieve('http://cfe.cboe.com/Publish/ScheduledTask/MktData/datahouse/CFE_U17_VX.csv')`

But it returns the same error.
The csv file can be download from chrome url easily. Help plz!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from urllib import urlopen`?

Comment: no, as mentioned i am using python 3 instead of 2.7 now